# Why is replica set mandatory for transactions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, distributed-transactions

As per MongoDB documentation, transactions only works for replica sets and not single node. Why such requirement? Isn't it is easier to do transaction stuff on a single node rather than a distributed system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementation of transactions uses sessions which in turn require an oplog.  Oplog is provided by replica sets for data synchronization between nodes.

> Isn't it is easier to do transaction stuff on a single node rather than a distributed system?

This is true but in practice, MongoDB positions itself as a high-availability database therefore there are rather few production deployments using a standalone server (as far as I know this isn't even an option in Atlas, for example). Hence lack of transaction support on standalone servers typically doesn't affect anything.

Conversely, implementing transactions *only* on standalone servers would not address the needs of the vast majority of MongoDB deployments/customers that use replica sets and sharded clusters.

For development purposes you can run a single-node replica set which gives you an oplog required for sessions and transactions but still only one mongod process.

Comment: There is also no reason you can't initiate a replica set on a standalone node, so you could have transaction support on a one-member replica set.